# Batch Adding 1 to a number untill Modulo divide 4

Tags: batch-processing

I'm gonna try to explain how my case is:

Lets say I have the number 30 and I want to make a batch script that adds 1 to that number untill its modulo divide 4

set /a number = 30 %% 4

how can I make it know to add 2 to 30 to make it mod 4 ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
@echo off
set num=30
:loop
set /a num=num+1
set /a number=num %% 4
if %number% NEQ 0 goto :loop
echo %num%
```